# Make a data frame from a list of sequences

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, lapply

With a list of sequences, for example,

```
datList <- list(One = seq(1,5, length.out = 20),
                Two = seq(1,10, length.out = 20),
                Three = seq(5,50, length.out = 20))
```

Is it possible to make a data frame so that the sequences are converted into columns. As in,

```
datDF <- data.frame(One = datList[[1]], Two = datList[[2]], Three = datList[[3]] )

> head(datDF)
       One      Two     Three
1 1.000000 1.000000  5.000000
2 1.210526 1.473684  7.368421
3 1.421053 1.947368  9.736842
4 1.631579 2.421053 12.105263
5 1.842105 2.894737 14.473684
6 2.052632 3.368421 16.842105
```

Within the context of my 'real' data I am working with many sequences and was hoping an `apply` (or similar) function could be used rather than manually creating the desired data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.frame`

```
datDFN <- data.frame(datList)
identical(datDF, datDFN)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: of course. whoops. I will leave up unless flagged as a duplicate. I did not see a similar question but seeing the answer, may have missed a similar application of `data.frame`.